# Getting the total sum in OBIEE without using SQL

Tags: obiee

I am trying to create an analysis in OBIEE. I am trying to get the total amount per customer. So 2 columns Customer and account balances.

A   111111
A   -111111
A   32000000
Grand Total 32000000

So the total would be 32000000 is there a way of just showing the grand total, like in SQL? I have tried multiple different aggregate rules

Comment: Your question is hard to comprehend. Screenshot maybe? Because what you're asking for sounds quite basic so it's preferable to be sure.

Comment: Is "account balances" a logical column inside a fact table? Does it have sum aggregation?